# Smart substr_count?

Tags: php

Okay, so suppose I have a string as follows: $string = "0::15:6:0";

Now, I want to count the number of numbers above 0 in the string, so I `substr_count($string, ':') + 1)` which provides me with the number 5 (which is technically correct, since although there are 4 actual numbers, the blank is used as a 0 in my code). But, that includes the 0's and blank 0's...which I do not want.

Any suggestions on how to make a "smart substr_count" to render me the number 2 (since there are two numbers not blank or 0, being 15 and 6)?

Comment: You could try using a regular expression to match numbers greater than 0. Maybe something like `/[1-9]\d*/`

Comment: 1. `explode` by `:` 2. Iterate over array from #1 and compare 3. ????????? 4. PROFIT! (this is the exact algorithm you're applying when doing that manually, not sure why you want something trickier when you developer)

Comment: Also, I think you're misunderstanding what substr_count does. It's actually counting the number of times ':' appears in the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Awesomeness in a tiny package:

```
$count = count(array_filter(explode(":",$string)));
```

This works because the string `"0"` is falsy.